# Whats the meaning of the logo on the amulet? is it permissible in islam?

Tags: shirk, sihr, tawiz

My Uncle received a object from a "Habib" from Indonesia asking him to keep it.
On the object there's some Symbol and Quranic verse on it. Does any one knows what is it? and what does the logo means?and also is it permissible in islamic teaching?[image]

Comment: All I recognize there are the words: "Allah"  الله , "Muhammad" محمد and the indian number 1317 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numerals the supposed quranic text is unreadable and the symbol has at least for me no meaning! Beside something which seems be written in Arabic letters but isn't (upper row the picture where thepic with the number is inside).